# AAD Refresh Tokens with Ionic 2 PWA

Tags: azure, ionic2, azure-mobile-services

I have an Ionic 2 app that works as a native app and as a progressive web app hosted on an Azure Web Site (which is not the same site as my API App Service Site). On the mobile side, I can get refresh tokens successfully by using the mobile SDK's login method and the making the REST call. However on the web side (PWA), I can't use the SDK to login because InAppBrowser won't work because `login.microsoftonline.com` sets **X-Frame-Options** to **DENY**. Therefore, I redirect the browser to `/.auth/login/aad?session_mode=token&post_login_redirect_url=` with a redirect URL coming back to my PWA index page.  That sends me the token back via #token which I am able to parse and use to successfully authenticate to my back-end API.

What doesn't work for me is calling `/.auth/refresh`.  That always gives me the error:

> The refresh request issued by sid... failed because no refresh tokens
>   were found in the token store.

The API App is configured to return an access token for `graph.microsoft.com` and I can see the refresh token in an initial call to `/.auth/me`.  I can also login directly via a browser session using `/.auth/login/aad` and no parameters.  There I can call `/.auth/me` and `/.auth/refresh` successfully

So what I am trying to figure out is how to make this work in the browser.  I need the user to get redirected back to my app so I specify the `post_login_redirect_url` parameter. With that the user gets logged in successfully and redirected to my app. However, that is when the call to `/.auth/refresh` fails with the error above. I am hoping this is just a matter of not passing the right parameters to the login endpoint but I am not sure.

Comment: Can you see the refresh token when you call `/.auth/me` on your Azure Web Site? If no, please follow the steps at [this blog post](http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/) to populate access tokens and refresh tokens into your app’s Token Store.

Comment: Yes.  I can see the refresh token and I can use the access token to access the Microsoft Graph.  I got a work-around working by basically following the mobile flow which uses window.open on /.auth/login/aad.  Using that route I can get a token that works and will give me a token via refresh, but it is not clean with the use of the popup.  Really trying to simplify the process here and keep the user in the same browser.